# Reload rails 4 view from on click, with params

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby, ajax, ruby-on-rails-4

I have an index view with a form, and I want to prepopulate the form with data from the database by having the user click a date on the calendar, so the user can see what that date has stored in it, and edit if they want. I have it set by default to today's date, and it works fine. If I hard-code it to some other date, it also works. But when I do it by clicking the date, the form never re-renders, it always shows data from today. At the moment I am doing it with an ajax call, which I suppose is not correct. I am using the gem bootstrap-datepicker-rails for the calendar. What is the best way to do it?

Here is my controller:

```
def index
    @item = Item.new
    @items = Item.all
    @date = params[:u_date] || Time.now.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
    @form_items = {}

    @items.each do |item|
      todays_trace = Trace.find_by(item_id: item.id, u_date: @date)
      if todays_trace
        @form_items[item] = todays_trace
      else
        @form_items[item] = Trace.new({input: "", notes: ""})
      end
    end
end
```

Here is my view:

```
    <div class="row">
      <%= form_tag "/traces_form" do %>
        <div id="datepicker">
          <input name="u_date" type="text" data-provide='datepicker' data-date-format="yyyy-mm-dd" value=<%= @date%>>
        </div>
        <% @form_items.each do |item| %>
          <%= render partial: 'trace_form', :locals => {:item => item[0], :trace => item[1]} %> 
        <% end %>
        <%= submit_tag "submit" %>
      <% end %>
    </div>
```

Here is my javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$("#datepicker").on("changeDate", function(event) {
  var u_date = $("input[name=u_date]").val();

  $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "/items",
    data: { u_date },
    success: function(){
      console.log("something happened")
    }
  });
});
</script>
```

And here is the rails log when I click on a date:

```
Started GET "/items?u_date=2015-04-29" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-04-30 17:04:31 -0700
Processing by ItemsController#index as */*
  Parameters: {"u_date"=>"2015-04-29"}
  Item Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "items".* FROM "items"
  Trace Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  "traces".* FROM "traces" WHERE "traces"."item_id" = ? AND "traces"."u_date" = ? LIMIT 1  [["item_id", 16], ["u_date", "2015-04-29"]]
  Trace Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  "traces".* FROM "traces" WHERE "traces"."item_id" = ? AND "traces"."u_date" = ? LIMIT 1  [["item_id", 17], ["u_date", "2015-04-29"]]
  Trace Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  "traces".* FROM "traces" WHERE "traces"."item_id" = ? AND "traces"."u_date" = ? LIMIT 1  [["item_id", 21], ["u_date", "2015-04-29"]]
  Rendered items/_new_item.html.erb (2.2ms)
  Rendered items/_trace_form.html.erb (0.5ms)
  Rendered items/_trace_form.html.erb (0.2ms)
  Rendered items/_trace_form.html.erb (0.2ms)
  Rendered items/_items.html.erb (9.7ms)
  Rendered items/index.html.erb within layouts/application (20.1ms)
Completed 200 OK in 707ms (Views: 703.6ms | ActiveRecord: 0.4ms)
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: 1) Small thing: `value=<%= @date%>` should probably have quotes around that: `value="<%= @date %>"` 2) did you look in the javascript console to see if you got any javascript errors? If so - can you paste them here (and by here I do not mean in the comments because code-formatting in comments is awful - please edit your question and add them in there)

Comment: There are no javascript errors in the console, there is only the console.log statement which lets me know that the success function went ping.

Comment: There are no errors because your success function isn't doing anything with the data.  Your success function should take a parameter `data` which will be the re-rendered page, in your current example. You may want your controller to return just a partial if it's an `xhr?` so that you can do something like `$('.row').html(data)` but that's once you've shown that you're getting the data back from the service. You can see what you're getting by doing `console.log(data)` in the success function, once you redefine the success function as `function(data){` `...` `}`.

Comment: Ahhh! Yes, you're right Cyberfox. I did what you suggested and it worked great. I knew I was missing some important piece about how ajax works. Thank you!